# PHP - Access to Font has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: php, cors, scrape

I need to get data from website but I have problem with scrape, I have error

> Access to Font has been blocked by CORS policy: No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

I have tried to fix it by adding the follwoing to the script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-domain.com');
```

But it is not working. I have also tried to put in `.htaccess` but it is not working there too, here is my code:

```
$link = 'http://jakartagrosir.com/products/search-0.html?keyp=sny+230&do=';
$html = file_get_contents($link);
$html = str_replace("../","http://thsoite.com/", $html);
$html = str_replace("styles/tf_black_white/image/favicon.png","http://thsoite.com/styles/tf_black_white/image/favicon.png", $html);

echo $html;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Should you be scraping the site?

Comment: Shouldn't the header be sent from the page you are trying to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the header on your server so that the page is allowed to connect to *you*(which you probably don't need anyway). But *they*, where they got the font, didn't do it. The page refers to their domain when it refers to the font. You will have to download the font and replace the link to their font with the link to your font on your server.